# How to keep QuickInfo and other services working when adding adornments that replace code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating adornments that have non-zero length. They replace code. I am creating a custom tagger to do this. That is, I am exporting an IViewTaggerProvider object where the tag type is IntraTextAdornmentTag.

The adornments display correctly. However, quick info no longer displays when I hover over the adornments. If the text hidden by the adornment would display a QuickInfo if ornamentation is disabled, I want the adornments that replaced the text to show the same QuickInfo if hovered over.

The same thing is true for other features like red squiggles. I want Visual Studio to display these if the text hidden by the adornments would otherwise have them.

Is there a way to "forward" such features form the hidden text to the adornments themselves?

Answer (score 0):

> How to keep QuickInfo and other services working when adding
> adornments that replace code?

I think you should use [IMouseProcessorProvider interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.imouseprocessorprovider?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to extend the mouse events for your adornments .

First, you should get mouse position with `e.GetPosition(_view.VisualElement)`.

Second, get the relative mouse position in the text buffer and stream position.

Then, get the `SyntaxToken` from the stream position with

```
var document = _view.TextSnapshot.TextBuffer.GetRelatedDocuments().First();
............
```

After that, set the info from [IAsyncQuickInfoSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iasyncquickinfosource?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to it.

**Besides**, since the code is too large, you can refer to [Identify mouse hover location in the editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-editor-api/wiki/Modern-Quick-Info-API) and [Modern Quick Info API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-editor-api/wiki/Modern-Quick-Info-API) for more detailed info.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know of the results.

Comment: I think that the "Identify mouse hover location in the editor" link points to "Modern Quick Info API". Did you mean to link somewhere else?

Comment: Oh, I think you could transfer `IQuickInfoSource` info into your adornments by mouse hover. See [Walkthrough: Display QuickInfo tooltips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-quickinfo-tooltips?view=vs-2019).